# How to index redirected url in google : Short url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, curl, url-routing

I am working on new project "short Url". I successfully create a short url, but when I submit a short url to google "webmaster tool", it gives me an redirect error.

**Now here is my 2 questions.**

Google search Image to clearly understand :

[image]

**1<sup>st</sup> Question**

shorturl websites like goo.gl, bit.ly etc, how they do that? how they submit their short url to google? I am thinking about, may me they are using curl? They check, if it is google bot so they run a curl and submit content to google.

Suggest me, what I need to do, I am using PHP.

**2<sup>nd</sup> question**

I am using internet from 10 years, I never see any search result linked with shorturl in google! Why? Here is my research what I found.

- Due to duplicate content google not show fake website on top.
- If user click on google search result, and after click, that link redirect to other url, google mark down rate to your website.

Friends tell me, What I need to know about this work? Thanks

---

**Extra: What is my aim:**

Create a short url website, and submit all short urls to google, many url means many chance to come up on google search.

In future if I want to place any ad on my website so I will do, but I needs many clicks from google search.

Currently I am only success in to create a short url...